# python - how to apply backspaces to a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
s = '--two \x08--three'
```

When I print, I get

```
--two--three
```

but can I do something to have

```
s='--two--three'
```

with out declaring it explicitly.

I do not need to store or even know about the back spaces. I just want to manipulate the text without the backspace characters there. How can I achieve this?

Edit: Hopefully I can clarify a little. Say I have two strings

```
test1 = 'a\bb' #b
test2 = 'b' #b
```

When they are printed, they are equivalent to the user, but `test1!=test2`. What I am doing is pulling some output from a terminal. This output has backspaces throughout. I want to be able to manipulate the end result, search for words, edit the string without worrying about the backspaces.

Edit 2: I guess what I really want is to set a variable as the result of a print statement

```
a = print("5\bA") #a='A' #does not work like this
```

Comment: What stops you from doing `s='--two--three'`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you please be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: I'm reading this as "I have a string, whose contents I don't know ahead of time, which may contain '\b' characters. How do I get a string which looks identical to the first string when printed, and which contains no backspace characters?"

Comment: What I don't get is that the title says "apply" backspace to a string, but the question looks like backspaces need to be replaced.

Comment: It sort of makes sense if you interpret "apply" as "act upon as if you were using a keyboard" applying "a\bc" means you type "a" followed by backspace followed by "c", for a final string of "c".

Comment: Sorry, I got called away. Kevin is spot on. I could replace the backspaces, but I would also want to remove the character before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply backspaces to a string using regular expressions:

```
import re

def apply_backspace(s):
    while True:
        # if you find a character followed by a backspace, remove both
        t = re.sub('.\b', '', s, count=1)
        if len(s) == len(t):
            # now remove any backspaces from beginning of string
            return re.sub('\b+', '', t)
        s = t
```

Now:

```
>>> apply_backspace('abc\b\b\b123')
'123'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is solvable by repeatedly applying a replace operation using a regular expression until the string contains no more backspace characters.  Alternatively, a more complicated regex could probably solve it in a single pass, but I'm going to go with the simpler solution.

```
import re

s = '--two \x08--three'

while '\x08' in s:
    s = re.replace('[^\x08]\x08', '', s)
```

The replace operation deletes all instances of a non-backspace character followed by a backspace character.  If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, the expression `'[^\x08]\x08'` can be decoded as follows:

```
[^       # Match any single character that is NOT one of the following:
   \x08     # A backspace character
]        
\x08     # followed by a single backspace character
```

The reason you need the loop is to handle the case where there are multiple backspace characters one after the other.  For example, with the string `'foocar\x08\x08\x08bar'`, each iteration would remove only the first backspace, like so:

```
'foocar\x08\x08\x08bar'
'fooca\x08\x08bar'
'fooc\x08bar'
'foobar'
```