# Python list comprehension remove element and next element from list

Tags: python, regex, coding-style, list-comprehension

I wanted to use list comprehension to remove all the occurrences of '\x08' (backspace character) from a list of chars I also wanted to remove the char before the '\x08'.

I ended up with a recursive function call but it would be nice to have a **readable**/pythonic one liner.

Example Input:

```
['a', 't', '+', 'B', 'A', 'D', '\x08', '\x08', '\x08','c', 'o', 'p', 's', '=', '?']
```

Desired Output:

```
['a', 't', '+', 'c', 'o', 'p', 's', '=', '?']
```

In case people want to see my current solution its.

```
def line_parser(self,line):
    if '\x08' in line:
        del line[line.index('\x08') -1]
        del line[line.index('\x08')]
        self.line_parser(line)
    else:
        self.something_else(line)
```

Comment: what should be the output of your example list?

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: There's a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362966/python-how-to-apply-backspaces-to-a-string). You'll need to `join` the list first

Comment: why doesn't the desired output have 'B' and 'A'?

Comment: How long might the list be? Currently your solution is O(n^2), wondering if that's a problem.

Comment: @JulienSpronck the '\x08' means backspace so 3 backspaces removes the 'B','A','D'.

Comment: @AlexHall The commands are very small <30 chars max.

Comment: What if backspace is the first character?

Comment: one-liner != Pythonic

Comment: @JulienSpronck Your answer seems to be on to something, why did you delete it? `not (x == '\x08') and not (j < len(l)-1 and l[j+1] == '\x08')`

Comment: @AlexHall it crashes specularity i added in a catch in my code but will leave it out to keep the example uncluttered.

Comment: @Arkadiy I deleted my answer because it won't work ... I don't think that it is possible to delete the three characters in one list comprehension because it requires the knowledge of the previously deleted character.

Comment: @JulienSpronck it's probably not *impossible*, but it would require some ugly, ugly hack and whatever you end up with is likely to be inefficient. Maybe I am wrong, and some elegant list-comprehension exists, but a straightforward for-loop seems like a very clean solution to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a Pythonic solution:

```
>>> data = ['a', 't', '+', 'B', 'A', 'D', '\x08', '\x08', '\x08','c', 'o', 'p', 's', '=', '?']
>>> newdata = []
>>> for c in data:
...     if c == '\x08' and newdata:
...         newdata.pop()
...     else:
...         newdata.append(c)
...
'D'
'A'
'B'
>>> newdata
['a', 't', '+', 'c', 'o', 'p', 's', '=', '?']
>>>
```

It's readable, explicit, and takes advantage of the performance characteristics of Python `list`s. Pythonic is not synonymous with "one-liner", in fact, often one-liner solutions are the opposite of Pythonic.