# Python - Process escape characters

Tags: python

I have a string with some ASCII escape characters. I would like **to store in a variable** the result of the output of `print()`. In my example the value `"pwd"`, without ASCII values.

Note: A replace function with Regex doesn't work, because there are some [backspaces](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) (`\x08`) to process and other [escape characters](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) (cursor movement for example). I don't want to develop manually a solution to manage each escape characters, I want to have a function to have the same result that `print()` output, but where I can store the result in a variable.

```
s = 'ld\x08\x08\x07m\x08\x07\x07pwd'
print(s) # pwd
print(repr(s)) # 'ld\x08\x08\x07m\x08\x07\x07pwd'
```

I tried to capture the output, but that doesn't work.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    print(s)
expected = format(f.getvalue())
print(repr(expected)) # 'ld\x08\x08\x07m\x08\x07\x07pwd\n'
```

Comment: `print()` doesn't return a value in Python. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Torxed Yes, I would like to know how I can have the same value printed in my terminal, here the value "pwd", but with a different function where I can store the result in a variable.

Comment: You aren't printing just three letters `p`, `w`, and `d`; you are printing all 12 characters, and your terminal *displays* that as 3 characters. It prints `ld`, backspaces twice so that the cursor is in the same cell as `l`, prints the bell characters (ding!), prints `m` *over* the `l`, backspaces again, dings twice, and finally, with the cursor over the `m`, prints the final three characters. This happens fast enough that all you see is the final result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - how to apply backspaces to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362966/python-how-to-apply-backspaces-to-a-string)

Comment: As far as *Python* is concerned, all of these characters are totally valid and thus are sent to your terminal. What your *terminal* then does with them is beyond Python's control. You cannot even know for sure `x08` is treated as a backspace by your terminal (although it's a good guess it is).

Comment: Capturing *just* the `pwd` involves simulating how your terminal handles it, byte for byte.

Comment: As an example of how this is entirely terminal-dependent, `man` pages treat something like `b\x08b` the way a typewriter would: display an `x`, backspace over it, and type *another* `x` on top, making it darker than a single `x` alone. That is, it *boldfaces* the repeated character. It's rare, but not unheard of, for a terminal to process `|\x08-` to display a single `+`-like character, rather than just `-`.

Comment: @JonahBishop I don't want to develop manually a solution to manage each escape characters, I want to have a function to have the same result that print() output, but where I can store the result in a variable.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for yours answers, is there a way to manage it with python directly, with a library ?

Comment: There is no such function. Primarily because there is no *need* for one. It's a good thing, then, that you *can* develop a solution to manage each escape sequence -- as programming languages go, Python is a suitable language to do that with.