# How to check the output in console after escaping?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume there are two strings:

```py
str1 = 'a\ba'
str2 = 'a'
```

If we use `print` to show those strings, all of them will print `a`.

But obviously, `str1 == str2` is `False`.How could I check whether they are the same after escaping?

Expected output like: `f(str1) == str2` is `True`,`f()` is the function to get the string after escaping.

I am not looking forward for some arithmetic ways to achieve that.

Comment: Do you want to check whether strings are different after printing? Or at what stage?

Comment: @pavel Yes, just want to know whether strings are different after printing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: This is terminal-dependant; see the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322564/python-process-escape-characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\b in ASCII is backspace (BS),it will not show in print function,

**1.** If you want it show in print function,you can use:

```
>>> print(repr(str1))
'a\x08a'
```

**2.** If you want use this str1 as print,you need to remove backspace :

```
>>> re.sub('.\b', '', str1)
'a'
```

Comment: You maybe misunderstand me.

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I want.

Comment: The second approach fails for strings like `ab\b\bc`. It should give `c`, but it instead gives `a\bc`. CC @KevinMayo

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon yes~it just an example, and it can do re.sub() again of ```a\bc``` to get ```c```

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes, thanks for explaining, so finally, I had to use some arithmetic ways to achieve that.

Comment: This answer might also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519338/5666087